# Volume of a polytope as its degenerates to be lower dimensional

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, simplicial-volume

Consider a polytope $P$ defined by the usual inequalities $A\mathbf{x}\leq \mathbf{b}$; let me assume that $P$ is not contained in a proper subspace.  A result which I believe to true, but am not having much luck actually finding a reference for is:

> The volume of $P$ varies piecewise polynomially with respect to $\mathbf{b}$.

I think I see the proof using mixed volumes or by decomposing $P$ into simplices (where the result is simple linear algebra), and presumably am just not finding the right words to Google, or this seems too obvious to mention for combinatorialists.

I have one slightly more specific result in mind that depends on this one; again, I am confidentish that I see the proof (just prove it for simplices), but it's really a tangent for the application where I want to use it and would much prefer to have a reference.  Now assume that I vary $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{b}_0+t\mathbf{b}_1$ linearly such that at $t\neq 0$, $\mathrm{Vol}(P_t)\neq 0$.

> **Theorem**: The order of vanishing of $\mathrm{Vol}(P_t)$ at $t=0$ is equal to the codimension of the span of $P_0$ (i.e. the number of independent linear equations it satisfies).

Comment: "Multivariate Ehrhart theory" might be a phrase to google.

Comment: @SamHopkins It's a good suggestion, but I do fear that the people working on Erhart theory think of the points above as too obvious to discuss.

Comment: For example, see Theorem 2 of https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00591-005-0094-9.pdf.

Comment: If A is integral you could of course blame the first result on Duistermaat-Heckman.

Comment: @AllenKnutson That really seems like overkill.  If there's another paper that proves this with DH, I'm happy to cite it, but in the context I'm writing, that's a very big tangent.